# How can I call homemade SQL function properly in symfony2.0 doctrine 2.2 with DQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, symfony, doctrine-orm, dql

I developed a SQL function in my oracle database :

```
     create or replace function test (var in number) return number  is
     begin 
     return 888;
     end;
     /
```

In sql, I can call this function like this :

```
    select test(1) as res from dual;
```

How can I call SQL function properly in symfony2.0 doctrine 2.2 ? 
I tried with this :

```
        $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('DUAL')->select("FUNCTION('test1',1) as res");
        die(var_dump($query->getQuery()->getResult()));
```

It works but it respond with too many lines and I don't know why :

```
    array(15) { [0] => array(1) { 'res' => string(3) "888" } [1] => array(1) { 'res' => string(3) "888" } [2] => array(1) { 'res' => string(3) "888" } [3] => array(1) { 'res' => string(3) "888" } [4] => array(1) { 'res' => string(3) "888" } [5] => array(1) { 'res' => string(3) "888" } [6] => array(1) { 'res' => string(3) "888" } [7] => array(1) { 'res' => string(3) "888" } [8] => array(1) { 'res' => string(3) "888" } [9] => array(1) { 'res' => string(3) "888" } [10] => array(1) { 'res' => string(3) "888" } [11] => array(1) { 'res' => string(3) "888" } [12] => array(1) { 'res' => string(3) "888" } [13] => array(1) { 'res' => string(3) "888" } [14] => array(1) { 'res' => string(3) "888" } }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the corresponding articles about adding a custom DQL function to Symfony:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/custom_dql_functions.html

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/cookbook/dql-user-defined-functions.html